# Figuring out all data sent in a POST query on a website with python requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have been studying POST/GET queries with python with a practical example of scraping data from a public site (in this case SEDI, the Canadian insider registry). This is with python 3.5 and requests 2.11.1.

So, on the following page one can enter a company insider name or other information:

https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTSelectSediInsider?menukey=15.01.00&locale=en_CA&gx_session=0

When opening this page, the client is sent two cookies with the following kind of content:

```
BIGipServerP_R1_sedi_443=rd1o00000000000000000000ffffac137017o443; path=/; domain=www.sedi.ca; Secure

JSESSIONID=0000RZjmIFv03gXCARzCPtvm2iC:188nefms0; path=/; domain=www.sedi.ca; Secure; HttpOnly
```

Let's assume I already know the insider number, for example RBIRCHA004 in this case. I have created a new session:

```
mySession = requests.session()
```

and filled all the form fields according to what gets sent when I use the site with my browser:

```
payload = {
  "pageName" : "https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/com/sedi/jsp/insider/selectSediInsider.jsp",
  "menukey" : "15.01.00",
  "locale" : "en_CA",
  "jspSynchronizerToken" : "yS7BQBPbm7w3dJqhbi_mGk_1477920341973",
  "PUBLIC_SEARCH" : "setFlag",
  "INSIDER_STATE" : "1",
  "INSIDER_KEY" : "RBIRCHA004",
  "INSIDER_LNAME" : "",
  "INSIDER_FAMILY_NAME_SEARCH_TYPE" : "2",
  "INSIDER_FNAME" : "",
  "INSIDER_GIVEN_NAME_SEARCH_TYPE" : "2",
  "INS_CORP_NAME" : "",
  "INSIDER_COMPANY_NAME_SEARCH_TYPE" : "2",
  "ISSH_NIPDB" : "",
  "issuer_name" : "",
  "ISSUER_NAME_SEARCH_TYPE" : "2",
  "Search" : "Search"
}
```

I have not found where the value for the `jspSynchroniserToken` comes from.

I have also browsed through the source in order to find js code which might have an effect on the queries. There is some at `/sedi/images/functions.js`but rather only a function for validating the form and checking if the user has pressed submit multiple times.

So - when i send this query with the parameters in the url (https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTSelectSediInsider?menukey=15.01.00&locale=en_CA) and post data like this:

```
mySession.request('POST', URL, data=payload)
```

I am only getting back the same search page - not a page with the results.

The reason I am trying to do an automatic data scraper is that the data is needed in my university studies, but getting it manually is very tedious, so i am trying to download it automatically and store in my sqlite db.

I am not yet very good with POST/GET nor js, but this is what I have managed to learn so far of the functioning of this site.

Could anyone point me forward in what I should be looking for? Am I not taking in account something with the headers?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: you can use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to see what exactly is send from browser to server when you use this url. Later you can use http://httpbin.org/post to see what is send by your script - it sends back all your payload, headers, coockies. see http://httpbin.org

Comment: `jspSynchronizerToken` can be unique value create every time you open page so maybe you have to use `GET` to get page and get unique `jspSynchronizerToken` before you use `POST`. btw. you can use `mySession.post(...)` instead of mySession.request('POST', ...)`

Comment: i check page. `jspSynchronizerToken` is in form as hidden input so you have to read page using `GET`, find `jspSynchronizerToken` using `html.parser`, `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`, and use it in `POST`